# Usage of CGridView and CButtonColumn (Yii Framework)

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I'm beginner for Yii and trying understand CGridView widget.

First i understand all of these codes :

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        "url",
        "allowRedirect",
        array(
            "name"=>"Kod",
            "value"=>array($model, "returnHTTPCode"),
            "type"=>"html"
            ),
        array(
            "class"=>"CButtonColumn",
            "template"=>"{update} {delete}",
            ),

        ),
));
```

Now i want to change *delete* button's url to `http://domain.com/?r=pano/deleteSite`. [In documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#deleteButtonUrl-detail), there is a deleteButtonUrl property, i'm trying to use it

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        "url",
        "allowRedirect",
        array(
            "name"=>"Kod",
            "value"=>array($model, "returnHTTPCode"),
            "type"=>"html"
            ),
        array(
            "class"=>"CButtonColumn",
            "template"=>"{update} {delete}",
            "deleteButtonUrl"=>"deleteSite"            
            ),

        ),
));
```

But i got `Use of undefined constant deleteSite - assumed 'deleteSite'` error.

And then i tried to use `buttons` property of CButtonColumn.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        "url",
        "allowRedirect",
        array(
            "name"=>"Kod",
            "value"=>array($model, "returnHTTPCode"),
            "type"=>"html"
            ),
        array(
            "class"=>"CButtonColumn",
            "template"=>"{update} {delete}",
            "buttons"=>array(
                "delete"=>array(
                            "url"=>"http://localhost/sitelerimacikmi/index.php?r=panos"
                            )
                ),

            ),

        ),
));
```

and got same error.

How can i use properties of CButtonColumn?

**Note** , English isn't my native language, so please use simple grammar, if possible.

Comment: OK i just solve problem with using `"deleteButtonUrl"=>"'?r=pano/deleteSite'"` instead of `"deleteButtonUrl"=>"pano/deleteSite"` . But still need clear answers for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    "url",
    "allowRedirect",
    array(
        "name"=>"Kod",
        "value"=>array($model, "returnHTTPCode"),
        "type"=>"html"
        ),
    array(
        "class"=>"CButtonColumn",
        "template"=>"{update} {delete}",
        "deleteButtonUrl" => "Yii::app()->createUrl('pano/deleteSite')" // <- changes here
        ),

    ),
));
```

Also, you can read this article: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify a URL then you must specify it as a PHP expression. Here is how is defined default value for delete URL in the `CButtonColumn` class ,

```
public $deleteButtonUrl = 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(
    "delete",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey)
)';
```

This url is evaluted using php eval function, in this expression `$data` is current model being rendered.

You should use:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    ...
    'columns'=>array(
        ...
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(
                "pano/deleteSite", array("id" => $data->primaryKey)
            )',
        ),
    ),
);
```